# REST request not allowed

Tags: node.js, angularjs, cors

I'm currently developing an AngularJS client with a node REST service. I get this error when I try to use the REST service locally:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://tasks.dev:12345/articles. Origin http://tasks.dev:8080 is    not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I already tried to set localhost to tasks.dev in my hosts file and run the app Angular app within a simple webserver. What else can I do?

Comment: Since you added the `cors` tag, did you set up CORS?

Comment: @Prinzhorn That's the point: How do I set that up in this scenario? In a different case you would use JSONP or something similar but now I'm using the same host (localhost, or tasks.dev) with different ports and it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: @schlingel because your browser uses the triple [`{protocol, host, port}`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454#section-4) as being an origin. If one of these changes, you need to enable CORS support. If you happen to use Express, [see this page](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html).

Comment: @robertklep Thanks! I totally forgot to add the CORS headers at the node site... You're right!

Answer (score 0):

I read that hosts file does not accept url with ports. If so define `http://tasks.dev` for instance, which listens to `8000` by default (or 8080).

Besides set up your server in your `app.js` to listen to `8000` (or 8080).

Hope this helps,

R.

Comment: That's the point I don't understand. I added tasks.dev as 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file. Why does the app seperate not only host but also port?

Comment: Your server may have open a port that is not 8000 or 8080. If you open the app using http://localhost, which port is used?

Comment: robertklep cleared the fog. The browser uses a triplet instead of the domain only. Additionally I forgot to add the CORS headers to my REST service. But to answer your question: My service runs (for testing) at port 12345 and the website at 8080.